# Find $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}{b_n={1\over n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}ie^{i^2\over n^2}}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Find $$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}{b_n={1\over n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}ie^{\left(i^2\over n^2\right)}}$$. Trying to present it in the form of a Riemann sum, I have arrived at: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{1\over n}{ie^{\left(i^2\over n^2\right)}\over n}$$. Thus, $\Delta x={1\over n}$. However, I am not really sure how to actually pick $\Delta$, $x_i$ or $f(x)$. How should I do that? It is really confusing. I have to take $x_{i+1}-x_i$ into consideration, and $\Delta x$ as well. I would fully appreciate your help.

Comment: Is it not $$\int xe^{x^2}dx$$

Comment: $({i\over n})^2$ is in the exponent.

Comment: Not just $i$, although it looks that ways, as it is tiny.

Comment: I have edited it to look a little better. Is my previous comment correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may write your sum as 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\times\frac{i}{n}e^{\large \frac{i^2}{n^2}}
$$ thus comparing with the following **Riemann sum**:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i+1} - x_{i})\times f(x_i)
$$ you get
$$
x_i=\frac i n, \quad x_{i+1} - x_{i}=\frac 1 n, \quad f(x)=xe^{x^2},
$$ and, as $n \to +\infty$, you easily obtain
$$
\lim_\limits{n\to \infty}{b_n}=\int_0^1xe^{x^2} dx=\frac 12\int_0^1e^{u} du=\frac{e-1}{2}.
$$