# Finding $ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot e^\frac{k^2}{n^2} $.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I'm asked to find   $ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot e^\frac{k^2}{n^2} $.

We can arrange the sum and we receive that our original limit is
$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{n} \cdot e^\frac{k^2}{n^2} $.

Taking $ x_k = \frac{k}{n}  $, that is the Riemann sum of the function $ xe^{x^2} $ on the interval $ [0,1] $.
Since that function is continuous and Riemann integrable on $ [0,1] $, the original limit is equal to $ \int_{0}^{1} xe^{x^2} $.
By that, the answer to this should be $ 0.5(e-1 )$.
However, when looking up larger and larger values of $ n$, the limit tends to $ \frac{1}{2} $.

What is incorrect with my train of thought?

Comment: $\int_0^1 x e^{x^2}dx$ is correct, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1209823/42969

Comment: Oh, that is reassuring. Thank you!

Comment: How did you  “look up larger and larger values of $n$”? I assume that there is an error in your calculation.

Comment: I wrote the expression in Symbolab where $ n = 10^4, 10^6, 10^8 $... Are those not large enough values? Is the website not accurate enough?